# Самый быстрый способ найти адреса файлов

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, файловая-система, ос

Допустим, есть директория `DIR1` вида `C:\\Users\\Admin`. Имеется также список, выглядящий примерно так: `['f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4', 'f5']`, и название файла: `FILE1`. Список представляет собой возможные имена папок по адресу `DIR1`.

Как быстрее всего найти все файлы с именем `FILE1`, если он может находиться только по пути `DIR1\<f1-f5>`, на один или на два уровня глубже? То есть, возможные адреса могут быть примерно такими: `DIR1\f2\FILE1`, `DIR1\f4\any_folder\FILE1`, `DIR1\f4\qwe\asd\FILE1`.

Пытался экспериментировать с `os.walk`, `glob`, `pathlib` и т.п., но самостоятельно определить не очень получается, да и вряд ли я использовал все возможные способы...

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# писал под linux, под windows может чтото пойти не так, точно не знаю.

import os

dir_name="/home/user1/development/stackoverflow/DIR1" # Задаем путь к папке где будет поиск файла

dir_map=os.walk(dir_name) # Создаем объект генератор, который при переборе возвращающий кортежы для всех вложенных папок где, нулевой элемент кортежа это адрес папки, первый элемент это список вложенных папок, а второй элемент список вложенных файлов.
for i in dir_map: # перебираем генератор
    if "FILE1" in i[2]: print(i[0]+"/FILE1") #  Если в списке файлов есть "FILE1" , выводим на экран.
```